# make the title post clickable vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm using vue + laravel and i try do display the data from api like this:

```
  <div v-for="article in articles" :key="article.id"  class="hieght">
            <div class="NewArticle">
             <h6 class="NewArticleTitle">{{ article.title.ar }}</h6>
            </div>
            <div>
            <p class="NewArticleBody">{{ article.excerpt.ar }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the script is:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            articles: []
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.axios
            .get('http://localhost:8000/api/articles/')
            .then(response => {
                this.articles = response.data;
            });
    }
}
```

But I want the post to open when I click on the title, I don't know how can i do that using vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a view component for your post. and make the h6 title tag a router-link tag that takes you to the post (or article) details page.